# installing opencv 2.4.9 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04

I have ubuntu 18.04 installed on my pc and I managed to install the newest version of opencv. **Nevertheless, I need an older version of opencv running on my pc, namely opencv-2.4.9.** So I deinstalled the new version of opencv, in order to install the old version. I followed like any instruction, which I could find so far in the internet, but unfortunately all of them were actually prepared for ubuntu 14.04 or earlier, so none of them worked.
So without going further into the details of those instructions, I would like to ask you, whether there you know of any possibility to install opencv-2.4.9 on ubuntu 18.04 (LTS)?

Best regards,
lonewolf

Comment: One instruction I followed is given in the following link: https://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/                                                                                                    I didn't want to go further into details since I assume that the instruction just cannot be used like this for ubuntu 18.04. But if necessary, I can provide you with more information of what I exactly did and what errors I obtained of course.

Answer (score 3):

you can get the 2.4 branch source here and build that, I think this is the best solution, and it worked for me on ubuntu server 18.04

```
    https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/2.4
```

instructions to build opencv from source after downloading the 2.4 branch as a zip and unzipping it can be found here:

```
    https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html
```

if you don't need any special exotic options, the basic build and install instructions can be summarized like this:

click on green button and download opencv2.4 zip release from the above github link; then at the commandline: (note that the build directory must be on a linux filesystem drive such as ext4)

```
unzip opencv-2.4.zip
cd opencv-2.4/
mkdir build
cd build
sudo apt install ninja-build ant cmake build-essential
cmake -GNinja ..
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

at this point you can now compile with opencv2.4! however, at runtime, you may run into an "error while loading shared libraries" which is fixed by this additional command:

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

why ninja instead of make? ninja can build in parallel on multiple processors so it is faster;
and now you can compile your source that worked in 16.04 with opencv 2.4.9;
if you download the source and compile it as shown above, you are done, you can stop here, this worked for me on xubuntu 20.04;
see also sigfriddo's answer;

if you do not want to download the source and compile,
other things you could look at: looks like

```
    sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

on a clean ubuntu 18.04 results in an opencv install that works if you use C++ opencv functions, but does not work if you use C opencv functions. In that case, it shows many pages of errors in the C opencv headers (even for an empty program that simply includes an opencv header and links to an opencv lib) - so it does find the headers and the libraries.

However, the exact same code compiles and runs perfectly on a clean ubuntu 14.04 and ubuntu 16.04 as well.
Sadly

```
    apt-cache policy libopencv-dev
```

this command shows that there is only one version of opencv available for ubuntu 18.04, however, if you install ubuntu/xubuntu 16.04 you will get a version that works with C code as well.

Suppose that the version you are looking for did exist, or will appear on ubuntu 18.04 at some point; the 16.04 version string is 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1 - in that case, the command to install that (non-default) version would be, for example:

```
    sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev=2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1
```

note that you need to check with the apt-cache policy command shown above to get the exact version string; for example, for build-essential, installing the default version included in ubuntu 18.04, the following 2 commands are equivalent:

```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential
    sudo apt-get install build-essential=12.4ubuntu1
```

in some cases you can delete the *.deb files from /var/cache/apt/archives/ then install the desired package, and copy the new *.deb files from this directory from the 16.04 system to the 18.04 system for example and then use dpkg -i *.deb to install them; but this works best for a small number of packages without dependencies; libopencv-dev has many packages and dependencies so this doesn't work;

so you can try to download the source and build from source; edit

```
    /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to uncomment the deb-src lines then do

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

and then sudo

```
    apt-get source libopencv-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

[jmarina's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7808477/jmarina) answer helped me a lot with this issue. In my case, instead of using the opencv/opencv repository, I used branch 2.4 from https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python.git as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779114/how-to-install-opencv-2-4-if-it-is-no-longer-supported) (it uses 2.4.13 though).

My steps were the following:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python.git
cd opencv-python/opencv
git checkout 2.4
mkdir -p build & cd build
cmake ../
cmake --build .
make install
```