# How to install OpenCV 2.4 if it is no longer supported?

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I am trying to run this code here https://github.com/feichtenhofer/gpu_flow/ which requires me to first install OpenCV 2.4. But I get the error below when trying to do so and I read that this means the version is no longer supported. So how can I install OpenCV version 2.4?

```
user:~$ pip install opencv-python==2.4
WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to unlock the collection!
WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to unlock the collection!
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==2.4 (from versions: 3.1.0.4, 3.1.0.5, 3.2.0.6, 3.2.0.7, 3.2.0.8, 3.3.0.9, 3.3.0.10, 3.3.1.11, 3.4.0.12, 3.4.0.14, 3.4.1.15, 3.4.2.16, 3.4.2.17, 3.4.3.18, 3.4.4.19, 3.4.5.20, 3.4.6.27, 3.4.7.28, 3.4.8.29, 3.4.9.31, 3.4.9.33, 4.0.0.21, 4.0.1.23, 4.0.1.24, 4.1.0.25, 4.1.1.26, 4.1.2.30, 4.2.0.32, 4.2.0.34)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==2.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that OpenCV 2.x has been removed from PyPI due to future deprecation.  You can figure this out by listing out all possible formulae for `opencv-python` using `pip`:

```
$ pip install opencv-python==                                                                                                            
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==
(from versions: 3.4.2.16, 3.4.2.17, 3.4.3.18, 3.4.4.19, 3.4.5.20, 3.4.6.27,
3.4.7.28, 3.4.8.29, 3.4.9.31, 3.4.9.33, 4.0.0.21, 4.0.1.24, 4.1.0.25, 4.1.1.26,
4.1.2.30, 4.2.0.32, 4.2.0.34)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==
```

The earliest version available on `pip` is 3.4.  Is there a particular reason why you want to specifically use OpenCV 2.4?

However, if it is your desire to do so, I would recommend visiting the repo that actually automatically releases OpenCV to PyPI through the `opencv-python` package:  https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python

From here, you must **manually** build the package yourself to generate a wheel installable through `pip` then install it yourself.  First you will need to use `git` to clone the repo.  Next, you will need to run the setup configuration to build the OpenCV package and compile it with version 2.4, then install it on your machine.

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python.git
$ cd opencv-python/opencv
$ git checkout 2.4
$ cd ..
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

The above ensures that the OpenCV source that accompanies the effort for building the Python package for OpenCV is set to version 2.4.

You'll have to wait a bit for this to build.  When it's finally ready, you will see a `dist` directory in the repo you just cloned.  Open this up and you'll see a `.whl` file that you can use to install OpenCV on your computer via `pip`:

```
$ cd dist
$ pip install <name of opencv 2.4>.whl
```

`<name of opencv 2.4>` should be the filename of the OpenCV 2.4 wheel that was built.  There should only be one file here with extension `.whl`.

Good luck!

---

P.S.  I would highly suggest you look for another package or do some code migrations to move to OpenCV 3 or 4.  There have been substantial improvements in these newer versions that are not seen with OpenCV 2 that help with performance and maintainability.

Comment: thank you for the very detailed instructions. The line "git checkout 2.4" returns me the error "pathspec '2.4' did not match any file(s) known to git." I have tried variants such as opencv2.4 and opencv-2.4 but to no avail.

Comment: @Kong you must go into the opencv directory inside the opencv-python repo. The repo checks out the official opencv repo too. Actually wait. I think you need to add the recursive option. Check my edit above with the clone method

Comment: @Kong thanks for the accept! Did you get it to work?