# Python - OpenCV - install older version

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install OpenCV 2.4.9 on my RaspberryPi and could use some help.

Apparently pip doesn't support it anymore and I'm not sure how to install a specific version using

```
sudo apt-get install python-openCV "blah blah blah"
```

Also, I should note I'm using Python 2.7 because the libraries I'm using haven't been updated for 3 yet.

["pip install python-opencv==2.4.9" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UljaQ.png)

---

Per the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779114/how-to-install-opencv-2-4-if-it-is-no-longer-supported), I run into an error when I run **python setup.py bdist_wheel**:

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/opencv-python/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-2.7/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/opencv-python/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-2.7/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 586, in setup
    languages=cmake_languages
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 240, in configure
    os.path.abspath(CMAKE_BUILD_DIR())))

An error occurred while configuring with CMake.
  Command:
    cmake /home/pi/opencv-python/opencv -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/pi/opencv-python/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-2.7/cmake-install -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=2.7.16 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so -DSKBUILD:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DPYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python -DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -DOPENCV_SKIP_PYTHON_LOADER=ON -DOPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=python -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DWITH_QT=4 -DWITH_V4L=ON -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DWITH_IPP=OFF -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-U__STRICT_ANSI__ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
  Source directory:
    /home/pi/opencv-python/opencv
  Working directory:
    /home/pi/opencv-python/_skbuild/linux-armv7l-2.7/cmake-build
Please see CMake's output for more information.
```

["setup.py" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt4l1.jpg)

---

The problem above was due to not having Qt4. I've since fixed it. But, now when I run setup.py I run into a new error:

```
copying _skbuild/linux-armv7l-2.7/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml -> _skbuild/linux-armv7l-2.7/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_upperbody.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 400, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 222, in main
    cmake_source_dir=cmake_source_dir,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 625, in setup
    cmake_source_dir, skbuild_kw['cmake_install_dir'])
  File "setup.py", line 312, in _classify_installed_files_override
    if not found: raise Exception("Not found: '%s'" % relpath_re)
Exception: Not found: 'python/cv2[^/]*\.so'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install OpenCV 2.4 if it is no longer supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779114/how-to-install-opencv-2-4-if-it-is-no-longer-supported)

Comment: @rayryeng, unfortunately not. I edited the post to reflect my current problem.